# how to use json data in dojo

Tags: ajax, json, dojo

Can anyone please help me to understand how should i access json data in js.
JSP-struts code to access. i am using struts2 , json, dojo. But getting issue accessing the data.

```
var chartData = dojo.xhrGet({
        url : "getJSONResult",
        handleAs : "json",
        preventCache : false,
        load : function(data) {
             //how to process

        }
    });
```

my struts.xml

```
<package name="json" namespace="/" extends="json-default">
    <action name="getJSONResult" method="execute"

class="uk.co.bandc.businessmonitor.web.controller.ShowTransactionAction">
        <result type="json" />
    </action>
</package>
```

My action class

```
package uk.co.bandc.businessmonitor.web.controller;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class ShowTransactionAction extends ActionSupport {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

int[] numberarray1 = { 10000, 9200, 11811, 12000, 7662, 13887, 14200, 12222, 12000,    
10009, 11288, 12099 };

public String execute() {

    return SUCCESS;
} // End execute()

public int[] getNumberarray1() {
    return numberarray1;
}

public void setNumberarray1(int[] numberarray1) {
    this.numberarray1 = numberarray1;
}

} // End class
```

Comment: Please fix the code-formatting, thank you.

Comment: What is the issue you are running into? does the data in your AJAX callback function not containing the JSON? If so, first thing to test is when you access your action using a URL typed into the browser location, do you get the JSON data back in the browser?

Comment: yes if i access http://127.0.0.1:8080/bizmon-web-user/getJSONResult i am getting result {"numberarray1":[10000,9200,11811,12000,7662,13887,14200,12222,12000,10009,11288,12099]} . I want to use the the values in the array as input to a chart. But not sure how to do that.

Comment: well, in your javascript function where you put the comment "//how to process", you have access to your data as data.numberarray1. That's what you should pass as a parameter to your chart.addSeries() as described in the tutorial from your link below (http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/charting/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of chart do you want to draw? your data seems to be one-dimensional. Typically for a cartesian chart (bar, line etc) you will need 2 dimensional data, for example:

```
var exampleData = 
[
{ time: 10, count: 7382 },
{ time: 20, count: 1852 },
{ time: 35, count: 2397 },
{ time: 50, count: 1442 },
{ time: 55, count: 1854 }
];
```

You can then use the dojox.charting.Chart2D to render the chart

See http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/charting/ for examples

Comment: If you will see on the  page http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/charting/ monthly sales pie chart with slice you can see var chartData = [10000,9200,11811,12000,7662,13887,14200,12222,12000,10009,11288,12099]; being used. My question is how to use this data if i get that data from server in the format {"numberarray1":[10000,9200,11811,12000,7662,13887,14200,12222,12000,10009,11288‌​,12099]}

Comment: did you try: chart.addSeries("SalesThisDecade",data.numberarray1);

Comment: Yah it is resolved now. Thanks. Actually i was doing something wrong in terms of syntax and it is resolved now.